# mysqli function error with php 7.0

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, mysqli

I had my previous web service code before PHP was updated to 7.0 and which was working perfectly:

```
class DbConnect{

const DB_HOST = 'localhost';
const DB_USER = 'root';
const DB_PASSWORD = '';
const DB_DATABASE = 'mans';

public static $conn;

public static function initialise()
{
    $conn = mysql_connect(self::DB_HOST, self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(self::DB_DATABASE, $conn);
    self::$conn = $conn;
}

public static function close(){
    $conn = null;
}
}
```

Now as mysql has been removed by php 7.0 and now we are supposed to use mysqli, I am getting the error,

> Exception:Call to undefined function mysql_query()

I have modified it to:

```
public static function initialise()
{
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','admin','admin','databasename');
}

public static function close(){
    $conn = null;
}
```

I have modified the php.in file already and restarted apache but nothing happened. Can someone tell me where is my error??

**EDITED**
I have been able to solve this. But I am still not being able to get the values from my database. It is instead showing me my else statement (which means it is not accessing my value from the database). Anything wrong in my code?

```
    $param = strtolower($param);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM Health where Title='" . $param. "'";
echo $sql;

    $dbResult = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);  

$HealthDetails=array();
$result=array();
if(num_rows($dbResult)>0){
    while($row=fetch_assoc($dbResult)){
    $HealthDetails[] = array('Title'=> $row['Title'],'Description'=> $row['Description'], 'Symptoms'=> $row['Symptoms'], 'Treatments'=> $row['Treatments']); //element names and names in db
    }
    free($dbResult);
    $result=array('HealthDetails'=>$HealthDetails);
 }
 return $result;
 }
 }
```

Comment: Wherever in your source using mysql_query, please replace it with mysqli_query

Comment: omg yes, such a silly mistake! I was stuck with it since morning. thanks a lot @Sagar

Comment: I have edited it @sagar . can you please check it again and help me out?

Comment: @ShaQueen can you show the error your getting now?

Comment: "But now I am having issues" — What issues?

Comment: @davejal Im not getting any error now but I am not getting my search values either

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), the first parameter of `mysqli_query()` should be a `mysqli` resource, as returned by `mysqli_connect()`. The second would be your query.

Your function call should look like this:

```
mysqli_query(DbConn::conn, $sql);
```

Comment: Try using `mysqli_num_rows()` for your `if` statement. @ShaQueen

Comment: Also noticing you used `$conn` in your DbConn class methods instead of $this->conn or self::$conn